# How to do reverse filter using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter the `nycflights13::flights` data, but am struggling with how to do it exactly.

I want the filter to remove rows that have dep_time data and `NA` for `arr_time`. However, when I use the below code it filters to show the flights with `dep_time` and `NA` for arr_time, but I want that subset removed from the entire dataset.

```
#filter(flights,!is.na(dep_time), is.na(arr_time))
```

I found this worked using base functionality, but want to learn how to do it using dplyr filter if possible

```
#flights[-which(!is.na(flights$dep_time) & is.na(flights$arr_time)), ]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike base subsetting, dplyr's `filter` only allows you to specify what to keep, not what to drop. So you have to take the complement of your predicate. By DeMorgan's Law your condition should be as follows:

```
flights %>% filter(is.na(dep_time) | !is.na(arr_time))
```

You can test that by using your base-r condition:

```r
all.equal(
  flights[-which(!is.na(flights$dep_time) & is.na(flights$arr_time)), ],
  flights[which(is.na(flights$dep_time) | !is.na(flights$arr_time)), ]
)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I think the question asker's confusion is that the conditions in `filter` specify what to keep, not what to exclude. It might be worth adding that to your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Actually base R `subset` works the same way. The issue is that @Mz2rA was used to using `x[-which(x$col == condition), ]`.

Comment: Old question but I came across it and wanted to add that you can reverse what to keep and what to remove with `!`. E.g., `filter(flights, !(!is.na(dep_time) & is.na(arr_time)))`